# Add your own variable in the object Kinetic.Animation()

Tags: variables, object, canvas, kineticjs

There is a code:

```
if (angleKeyS == 'open') {
  angleKeyS = 'close';
  anim.start();
}
```

within the animation variable changes the value of `angleKeyS = 'open'`

```
var angleKeyS = 'open'; // Global variable, default
// ...
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
  // ...
  angleKeyS = 'open';
}, layer);
```

How to make a variable 'angleKeyS' part of the object 'anim', instead of a global variable?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651167/kineticjs-object-with-added-property-to-json) creates an object `var test = new Object(); test.kinetic = new Kinetic.Animation(..); test.angleKeyS = "string";`, but it is interesting solution according to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the angleKeyS property like this:

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
  // ...
}, layer);

anim.angleKeyS='open';
```

And use it like this:

```
if (anim.angleKeyS == 'open') {
  anim.angleKeyS = 'close';
  anim.start();
}
```